# Is it true that $a_n \to \infty$ implies that $a_n$ is definitely increasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, solution-verification

Consider a sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that $a_n \to \infty$; is it true that $a_n$ is (at least definitely) increasing?
Intuitively I would say yes, I don't see how is possible that a sequence can go to infinity without increase (at least from a certain point on); I've tried to think to a counterexample but I couldn't find it, so I've tried to prove it but I suspect that I'm doing something wrong.

By hypothesis $a_n \to \infty$, so for all $M\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $N_M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N_M \implies a_n \geq M$; now (this is the step I'm unsure about) I would like to use the fact that $M\in\mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary to let $M=a_{n-1}$, so I would get that $n \geq N_M \implies a_n \geq a_{n-1}$ and this is the definition of definitely increasing function since this is valid only for $n \geq N_M$.

However I do believe that this proof is not valid, because in the definition of limit $M$ is considered fixed while $a_{n-1}$ can vary because of its dependence on $n$; so I think I'm not allowed to choose $M=a_{n-1}$. Is my suspect correct and this proof is not valid?

Hints of are more welcome that resolutions :) thanks!

Comment: Hint: there is a common expression - two steps forward, one step back

Comment: I have no idea what " (at least definitely) increasing" means. I suspect that you meant "eventually increasing" in place of "definitely increasing"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence
$$a_n = n + 2 \times (-1)^n$$

tends to $+\infty$ but is not definitely increasing.

Comment: I see, thanks! Can the counterexample $a_n=\begin{cases} n, \ \text{if} \ n \ \text{even} \\ 0, \ \text{if} \ n \ \text{odd}\end{cases}$ be valid too?

Comment: @SabakuSouSou No, your sequence does not tend to $+\infty$, since it takes infinitely many times the value $0$. The sequence must be "globally" increasing...

Comment: the limit of the piecewise sequence I've proposed isn't $\infty$ because the definition of limit requires $n \geq N_M \implies a_n \geq M$ and this fails for all the odd integers greater than $N_M$, because it is not always $0 \leq M$ for all $M\in\mathbb{R}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @SabakuSouSou Yes, just take $M=1$, and you can see that there is no $N_M$ satisfying the definition, as you said.

Comment: What does "definitely increasing" mean (and how do you know)???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If you read the OP's question, this is rather clear that it means "increasing from a certain point".

Answer (score 0):

A counter-example can be constructed by taking any sequence which tends to $\infty$ and replacing every other term in a way that the pattern is one of:

decrease, increase, decrease, increase... or similar

(actually some of the increases could be decreases as well, but the point is you can build in decreases throughout the whole sequence).  The replacement terms still need to tend $\infty$ as well but there are many ways to ensure that.

Comment: The question owner said hints were preferred over a resolution, so I tried to give more of a hint, but I see that's been downvoted and the question owner has accepted an answer which gives a complete solution.  Oh well, you live and learn...